# In react-advance-jalaali-datepicker, the preSelected value doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I am using the library react-advance-jalaali-datepicker, and I have added a preSelected value. It shows the preSelected date on the input but when the datePicker itself is opened, there is no selected date and the current month and year is showing, not the month and year of the preSelected date. Any ideas?

```
            <DatePicker
                    controllValue={true}
                    inputComponent={this.DatePickerInput}
                    placeholder="انتخاب تاریخ"
                    format="jYYYY/jMM/jDD"
                    cancelOnBackgroundClick={true}
                    preSelected={
                      " 1398/05/02"
                    }
                    inputTextAlign="center"
                    onChange={(timeStamp, formattedDate) => {
                      console.log(
                        "this.props.Inquiry.userData.LatestInsuranceStartDate",
                        this.props.Inquiry.userData.LatestInsuranceStartDate
                      );
                      this.datePickerOnChange(
                        timeStamp,
                        formattedDate,
                        "LatestInsuranceStartDate"
                      );
                    }}
                    id="startDate"
                  />
```

[image]